# Convert char to int using only write function

Tags: c, type-conversion

For example, i have:

```
int num = 23;
char s;

s = num - '0';

write(1, s, 1); // return 23
```

How can i make it? No functions allowed except write();

Comment: `write()` doesn't do any conversion, it just sends bytes to a device, in this case the terminal. You're only writing 1 byte, so it can't possibly print `23`.

Comment: The ASCII value of `'0'` is `32`, since `num - '0'` will be a negative number. How do you expect that to print `23`? If `num` were a single digit you could use `num + '0'` to get its character code.

Comment: If you want to print multiple digits like this, you'll need a loop. But it will be hard to print them in the correct order; it's easy to print them in reverse order.

Comment: 1. Yep, that's the case. I know, that i can't print 23 only with 1 byte. 
2. I don't need a character code, i need it to be in digit format.

But is there any possibilities to make a code that returns 23? I don't know, somehow? Maybe there is no even a solution to this?

Comment: To print a number, you need to get the character code corresponding to each digit.

Comment: what does it mean `"returns"`

Comment: Return 23 or print 23?

Comment: Prints, print 23

Comment: I think getting the character code to each digit will be too hard. I mean, this will be a big code. Oh, wait. But, maybe you are right

Comment: Can i use char* s = num? Not for the function. char* working like a string, right?

Comment: No you can't do that. That will use `num` as a memory address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first digit of a number, you have to divide it by the highest power of 10 below the number, then add that to the character code of `'0'`. After printing that digit, get the remainder from that power of 10, and repeat the process with the next lower power of 10. Keep going until the power of 10 reaches 1.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int num = 235872347;
    if (num < 0) {
        num = -num;
        write(1, "-", 1);
    }
    int pow10 = 1000000000; // maximum power of 10 in signed 32 bit
    // first skip leading zeroes
    while (num < pow10) {
        pow10 /= 10;
    }
    for (; pow10 > 0; num %= pow10, pow10 /= 10) {
        char digit = '0' + num / pow10;
        write(1, &digit, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, thank you. That a bit confusing code, i mean pow10 /= 10 can be in parentheses, but yes. Thank you!)

Comment: I was amazed that it worked on my first attempt, I was sure I was going to be off by 1 somewhere.

Comment: Um, i don't know if your code is working. I will just use a pattern of this

Comment: Okay, that's great!)

Comment: Sorry for saying mistake about it, i know it's stupid, that is my task in courses. But it's not working with number -2,147,483,648. I know why, because integer doesn't have 2,147,483,648 positive number

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the number in variable `num`: (we are building the number backwards)

```
#define BASE 10  /* code works for any base between 2 and 16 (both incl.) */
#include <unistd.h>

int main() 
{
    unsigned long num = 235834534472347;
    char buffer[20], *p = buffer + sizeof buffer;
    while (num > 0) {
       *(--p) = "0123456789abcdef"[num % BASE];
       num /= BASE;
    }
    /* this will output the string 235834534472347 */
    write(1, p, buffer + sizeof buffer - p);    
}
```

As you can check, the only function called is `write(2)`.